# Looking for a theory

Tags: discourse-analysis

I am working on selected speeches of a politician. In the work, I would like to show in which way these speeche create emotion and hope, through the speech acts which are used.

Apart from the speech act theory, What other linguistic theory can I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a big discipline, not exactly linguistics, called [rhetoric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhetoric) with literature going back to classic antiquity (e.g., Cicero). [Figures of speech](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Figure_of_speech) are a part of rhetoric and offer themselves as a tools for analysis of speeches.

Comment: Yeah. Agree. Rhetorical devices can be helpful. And also logical, ethical, and emotional appeals in the field of rhetorics may be instrumental, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with theories of intonation.There’s an amazing book by O’Connor & Arnold called « Intonation of colloquial English ». It may be useful for you.